# Woocommerce REST API not considering discounts and coupons

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, wp-api

I am trying to create an order on my WooCommerce store from my mobile application using the REST API v2. The order is created successfully but I can't find any solution to the following issues.

1. I send a `coupon_lines` array within the `order` object and when the order is viewed on the admin panel, it shows the coupon there but the order `total` is not affected at all.
2. Then I decided to calculate the `total` and discounts based on the applied coupon manually. I tried to set `discount_total` within the `order` object equal to the amount which is the value of the coupon. I also update the `total` manually as well. But again, all the values that I pass are ignored and the order `total` is equal to the sum of the prices of all line items (ignoring `discount_total`).

Here is a sample JSON object that is sent to the API from my app.

[image: The order total should should be 5000, but it is 10000 in the WordPress admin panel because the Coupon Code for 5000 has no effect. Also, the <code>discount_total</code> has no effect. It is 0 in the response <code>order</code> object.]

What other options do I have to set an order total and discount manually? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your `coupon_lines` array, each item in the array needs 2 properties: `code` (the coupon code itself) and `amount`, which is either a flat fee (eg 50.00 off) or a discount (eg 10% off). Your structure ends up looking like:

```
"coupon_lines": [
    {
        "code": "MYCODE1",
        "amount": "10.00"
    },
    {
        "code": "MYCODE2",
        "amount": "25.00"
    }
]
```

If you're already doing this - consider posting an example request here.

Comment: Hi. I looked at the docs and thus have the field `discount` instead of `amount`. Also updated the code with image of the JSON request object.

Comment: [The REST API docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v2.html#orders-properties) say it should be `amount`.

Comment: When I tried with `amount` instead of `discount`, this is what I get (https://i.imgur.com/45O9cFz.png)
I think you referred to old docs. Here (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties) are the docs for REST API v2.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It looks like you can't use this as an actual feature until WC API v3, which is in development.  The fields you've tried to set (such as total, discount_total etc) are all read-only so they will not effect anything. You might have to end up going through each line item and removing values from the `total` field (not subtotal!)

Comment: I actually don't even have `total` or `subtotal` in any of my `line_items` objects. They just have `product_id` and `quantity`. I understand that `discount_total` is readonly, but is there no way to override the value of `total`?

Comment: You should be able to add `total` and `subtotal` as fields in each line item, so you might want to consider adding a `total` field which is 5000 - your discount.

Comment: So for a fixed discount, I will have to divide that discount proportionally amongst all products. And for a percentage discount, I can simply reduce the price by that percentage. Right? But this is such a dirty way.